# How can I get the Class object in a static method without using the class name?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, reflection, static

I have

```
public class A {
    static X s_x = new X(A.class);
}
```

and

```
public class B {
    static X s_x = new X(B.class);
}
```

and so on for many classes without any special relationship or commonality. What I really wish I could do is have s_x initialized in a superclass, but with descendant-class-specific code; this is impossible since static code is not overridable. So, I want to at least make my copy-paste easier. I want a magic expression which evaluates to the Class object, i.e. to write:

```
    static X s_x = new X(/* magic expression here */);
```

where the magic expression is the same regardless of the class in which I declare my X in, but does the same as the examples above. Second-best option would be a static method to the same effect.

Notes:

- Java 6 if possible.
- This question is not (necessarily) about logging...

Comment: Does class `A` and class `B` have some form of relationship?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: none. Edited to make this clearer.

Comment: You can use getClass() method.

Comment: @RohitKumar.. No, it's static reference variable.

Comment: is it about a static logging variable?

Comment: I dont understand. Do you need to inject `static X s_x = new X(...);` in all classes ?

Comment: @wrm: It might be, but I made this question more general. I'd appreciate a reference to a logging-specific SO question though.

Comment: @vels4j: Not necessarily in all classes, but that would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the answers here have the idea for a solution, but not quite the code snippet I need. So here it is, working on any JVM:

```
static X s_x = new X(getClassStatic());

public static Class<?> getClassStatic() {
    try {
        // we're using the third highest stack element, since the
        // first highest is the getStackTrace() method, followed by this method itself. We
        // want the calling code's class.
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();
        return Class.forName(name);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // shouldn't be able to get here...
        return null;
    }
}
```

or, for selected JVMs, as per Peter Lawrey's suggestion:

```
static X s_x = new X(getCallerClass(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this strange requirement once and I tried to search but did not find anything, so I guess the answer is it's not possible may be.

But I was told to rethink my approach and when I tried I figure out the same solution without this strange requirement. So please rethink your approach. I'm sure you'll be able to solve it like me. Also, if you can post the problem/scenario you are trying to solve,may be I can help.

Comment: You're actually right, and your answer not only inspired me to provide an answer myself but also to get the guy who's making me use this code try to go another way.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7 you can use the class `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles` for this:

```
Class c = MethodHandle.lookup().lookupClass()
```

You will probably get a warning about using a raw type instead of the parameterized version `Class<X>` but I can't see how you can avoid that without reverting to hard-coding the class name yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In the HotSpot/OpenJDK you can use

```
 Class c = Reflection.getCallerClass(1)
```

Note: this is an internal API and might not work on all JVMs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that should work in Java 5+ JVM and doesn't add any additional imports to your code:

```
new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass()
```

It creates an anonymous inner class, gets its `Class` object, then gets its enclosing class instance, which should be your class.  For example:

```
public class HelloClass {
    static final Class<?> THIS_CLASS = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(THIS_CLASS); // prints "class HelloClass"
    }
}
```

In the context of your question:

```
static X s_x = new X(new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass());
```

Comment: Nice... and it seems this can be optimized at compile-time, as opposed to looking at the stack trace. However, you can't really put this in a method, and the `new()` is pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to extract the class name from the current stack-trace (see [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29)), which will give it to you as a `String`, from which you can get a `Class` object using `Class.forName(String)`, but that's much uglier than your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but some re-factoring in your approach is needed:

## Try this out:

```
class X
{

   public X(String cName)
   {
     try
     {
       Class.forName(cName);
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException cne)
       {}
   }
}

public class Test
{
    static X x1 = new X(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create a logging object, you can use [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html) to inject a logging object for you.
Example from the page:

```
@Log
public class LogExample {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Something's wrong here");
  }
}
```